# RoR crash on save "You have a nil object and you didn't expect it"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a RoR object graph i'm saving. user has a list of sections. when a request comes in, i delete all current user sections, and repopulate with new ones.

```
def set_current
  @courses = params[:courses]
  user = current_user
  user.points = params[:points].nil? ? user.points : params[:points].to_i
  UserSection.delete(user.user_sections)
  @courses.each do |c|
    new_section = UserSection.new()
    new_section.user = user

    new_section.save
  end
  user.save

  head :ok
end
```

when i save, i get this:

```
NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.new_record?):
  app/controllers/schedule_controller.rb:32:in `set_current'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.6/bin/rdebug-ide:82
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.6/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
  /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/bin/rdebug-ide:19
```

thoughts on what's actually going on? the save happens successfully - makes it to the db and everything.

*edit*: the exception (schedule_controller.rb:32) is the call to user.save

Comment: What is on line 32 of the ScheduleController ?

Comment: what happens when the user has no user_sections? it seems you need to check for null user_sections.

Comment: @zabba it's the call to user.save

Comment: @mossplix - sure, but that's not the case here

Comment: If it's valid to do: if you replace `new_section.user = user` with `new_section.user_id = user.id`, then does it work? And what is the code between `new_section.user = user` and `new_section.save`, if any ?

Comment: no luck. and, the lines in between are just populating simple values (strings, integers, w/e). not null.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the first line with (if that's where your error is)

```
UserSection.delete(user.user_sections) if user.user_sections
```

But like Zabba said, code listings would be helpful.

Comment: yeah, edited for more detail. the exception is on the call to user.save

Comment: It seems you have callbacks on your User model that are failing because user is nil (note the nil.new_record? error). Given user.points doesn't raise an error, look in UserSection.delete(user.user_sections): maybe you're accidentaly destroying user after user_sections?